# Song is not playing using MediaPlayer. Error: JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails and JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

The below code is a section of a music player project in which songs are fetched from External Storage and displayed using RecyclerView. Using the Toast I displayed the path and its displaying correct path. But still on clicking a particular song the song is not getting played.
Following Error is shown:

> 2021-02-13 13:07:05.727 4846-4846/com.mohit.musicplayer
> E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
>
> 2021-02-13 13:07:05.727 4846-4846/com.mohit.musicplayer
> E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0

```java
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.song_name.setText(data.get(position).getSong_name());
    holder.song_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
            String path =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getPath()+"/"+data.get(po sition).getSong_name()+".mp3";`
            Toast.makeText(context,path,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context,uri);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    stop();
                }
            });

        }
    });

   
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public void stop()
{
    if(mediaPlayer!=null)
    {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer=null;
    }
}
```